# Инициализация массива листов

Tags: java, массивы, generics

Нужно задействовать массив листов при инициализации таким образом

```
List<String>[] FinishFile = new ArrayList<String>[12];
```

Eclipse выдал ошибку:

> Cannot create a generic array of ArrayList

в итоге прокатил такой вариант

```
List<String>[] FinishFile = new ArrayList[12];
```

Почему?

Comment: Дженерики в Java :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что компилятор не может вам гарантировать типобезопасность (type safety) для массивов обобщенных типов, потому что массив может быть приведен к более широкому типу (с потерей информации от  обобщенном типе).

Например, если бы первый вариант работал, это приводило бы к таким ситуациям:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ints.add(1);

List<String>[] a = new ArrayList<String>[5]; // предположим, это допустимо
Object[] o = a;   // вполне разрешенный upcast, но информация о generic типе потерялась
o[0] = ints;

String s = a[0].get(0); // ошибка приведения типа во время выполнения программы
```

Система generics же в Java направлена на проверку типов и гарантии безопасности типов как раз на этапе компиляции. Поэтому вы будете вынуждены написать:

```
List<String>[] a = new ArrayList[5];
```

и получите Warning от компилятора и предупреждение в IDE, после которого ответственность за потенциальные ошибки перекладывается на вас.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

PS. Вообще массив коллекций — довольно сомнительная практика, обычно массивы применяются для примитивных типов там, где есть какие-то вычисления или сериализация/десериализация в бинарные данные.

Используйте `List<List<String>>` и живите в типобезопасном мире.

Comment: `Вообще массив коллекций — довольно сомнительная практика` — может есть какой-нибудь ruSO/enSO ответ, поясняющий подробно это?

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ все стало понятно. мне придется использовать List<<String>[] т.к. массивы очень быстры. а мне нужно довольно быстро обрабатывать около 600 метров эксель файлов, но я проверю и с List<List<String>>.